# Evaluate the integral $ \iiint_{B}3x^2+y^2+z^2+2 \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z .$

Tags: integration

> Let $ B $ be the unit ball $ \{ (x, y, z)\in\mathbb R^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2<1 \} $. Evaluate the integral
>   $$ \iiint_{B}3x^2+y^2+z^2+2 \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z $$

The hint says we should use Stokes, so we have:
\begin{align}
\iiint_{B}3x^2+y^2+z^2+2 \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z&=\iiint_{B}\nabla\cdot(x^3, \frac{1}{3}y^3, \frac{1}{3}z^3)\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z+\frac{8}{3}\pi\\
&= \iint_{\partial B}x^4+\frac{1}{3}y^4+\frac{1}{3}z^4\mathrm{d}S+\frac{8}{3}\pi\\
\end{align}

How to continue then?

The question is from: (6) of https://math.uchicago.edu/~min/GRE/files/week3.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similarily as @Botond, I also see no reason to invoke the Divergence theorem here. However, I would like to add the following. 
Notice that, by symmetry,
$$ \int_B x^2 \, dV  = \int_B y^2 \, dV =  \int_B z^2 \, dV = \frac{1}{3}\int_B x^2+y^2+z^2\, dV. $$
Hence
$$ \int_B 3x^2+y^2+z^2 \, dV =  5 \int_B x^2 \, dV =  \frac{5}{3}\int_B x^2+y^2+z^2 \, dV. $$
Now use spherical coordinates to get
$$ \int_B x^2+y^2+z^2 \, dV = \int_{r=0}^1 \int_{\theta=0}^\pi \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} r^2\cdot r^2\sin\theta \, d\phi \, d\theta \, dr
= 2\pi \int_0^1 r^4 \, dr \int_0^{\pi} \sin\theta \, d\theta = \frac{4\pi}{5}. $$
Hence
$$ \int_B 3x^2+y^2+z^2+2 \, dV = \frac{5}{3}\frac{4\pi}{5} + \frac{8\pi}{3} = 4\pi. $$

Comment: Nice! No reason to invoke the Divergence theorem+1. Thank you~

Comment: Nice usage of the symmetry  :)

Comment: @Botond Thank you, that's very kind of you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with spherical coordinates: Let $\vec{r}=[x, y, z]^T=[r\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi), r\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi), r\cos(\theta)]^T$ And the Jacobian is $r^2 \sin(\theta)$. So the integral is:
$$\int_B 3x^2+y^2+z^2+2 \mathrm{d}V=$$
$$\int_{B}2x^2+2+r^2 \mathrm{d}V=$$
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} (2r^2\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\varphi)+2+r^2)r^2\sin(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}r \,\mathrm{d}\varphi \,\mathrm{d} \theta$$